# Graph Theory Connectivity and Diameter of Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

> Let G be a graph of order n with κ(G) ≥ 1. Prove that n ≥ κ(G)[diam(G) - 1] + 2.

κ(G) meaning connectivity of G and diam(G) meaning diameter of G.

I know that κ(G) and diam(G) are inversely related, but I still need help approaching this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you had a theorem which says that, for any two vertices $x,y$ in a $k$-connected graph, there are $k$ internally disjoint paths connecting $x$ and $y$? All right, then. Choose vertices $x,y\in V(G)$ so that $d(x,y)=\text{diam}(G)$, and then construct a set of $\kappa(G)$ internally disjoint paths connecting $x$ to $y$. Each of those paths has length at least $\text{diam}(G)$, and so has $\text{diam}(G)-1$ internal vertices. Since they are internally disjoint, those $\kappa(G)$ paths have at least $\kappa(G)[\text{diam}(G)-1]$ internal vertices among them. Add to that the endpoints $x$ and $y$, that makes $\kappa(G)[\text{diam}(G)-1]+2$ vertices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but doesn't each of those paths have at MOST diam(G) not at LEAST diam(G)?

Comment: The length of a path from $x$ to $y$ is **at least** $d(x,y)$, and $x,y$ were chosen so that $d(x,y)$ is **equal** to $\text{diam}(G)$. In other words, $d(x,y)$ is the length of the **shortest** path from $x$ to $y$; our paths may not be the shortest $x,y$-paths, so they may be longer than that, but not shorter.